# "You need to enable javascript to run this app". basic react app not running in browser

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Having some trouble debugging my react app. This app was created using create-react-app, so I should be able to run 'npm start' and see the app run in the localhost window in my browser, but instead I see nothing, and in the Elements tab of chrome devtools shows a  tag saying "You need to enable javascript to run this app".

Not sure what is going on here. I had this app running perfectly fine yesterday, and I didn't change anything to the package.json.

Here's what my package.json looks like:

`

```
`{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}`
```

`

Can anybody help me with this? I tried adding a common solution, to add "proxy": "localhost:5000", but that didn't solve the problem.

I was expecting the app to successfully start in the browser.

Comment: Did you check whether javascript is deactivated in your browser settings?

Comment: That or a browser extension (ghostery, ublock, adblock, etc) that could be blocking javascript in that page.